# show images on UITableView from Json Array

Tags: json, image, uitableview

I have a UITableView From an Array created with JSON, but I dont know how show images from the array. The images are an strings urls, but I cant show it on the UITableView.

I know the code to show text is the next code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[lista objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
```

but i cant use this to the urls with the images, because "Images" is a string data:

```
 cell.imageView.image = [[lista objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Images"];
```

how can I show the images from an URL?

thank you

Comment: So when your handling a JSON I'm expecting that your loading the data from a server and the strings of the images contains an url where the images have been stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the images actually.

As you are a beginner, I would suggest you download and use [AFNetowrking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking),

AFNetworking has a simple class to download UIImages from a URL:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```

If you are in a Tableview cell, you simple use the TableView's cellImageView, instead of creating a new UIImageView, like:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[lista objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Images"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myplaceholderimage.png"]];
```